# Does Jetbrains Upsource have an API?

Tags: upsource

Would like to write some integration for Upsource, does it have an API ?  I can't seem to find one.

Perhaps the creators could answer if there is or will be one ?

Comment: It would be nice if you could comment why it was down voted or voted to close.   I haven't been on here for a while, perhaps rules have changed?

Comment: I think it's probably because the question isn't really about programming. I upvoted though... found it through Google looking for the Upsource API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upsource will have an HTTP API starting with version 2.0 that is [currently in Early Access](https://www.jetbrains.com/upsource/nextversion/).

So far we don't have any documentation for the API though, apart from a mere listing of the exposed methods that is accessible from the right side of the footer in Upsource 2.0 builds.

EDIT: Basic documentation is [now available](https://upsource.jetbrains.com/~api_doc/index.html)

Comment: Even though the current Upsource version is 2.5, it’s still hard to find API documentation on the JetBrains website. The reason for that might be that the docs are currently pretty basic. You can find them at `/~api_doc/index.html` on your Upsource server. If you don’t have one, you can use JetBrains’ server: https://upsource.jetbrains.com/~api_doc/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to start is https://upsource.jetbrains.com/~api_doc/index.html which is JetBrains code review server documentation.
If you want to know for what version the documentation is check bottom left here: https://upsource.jetbrains.com